# Search inside a pdf without opening the contents

Tags: java, pdf, search

I would like to create a searchview in android in a pdf file without opening the content and if the pdf has the searched word then it will show only the title/titles of that pdf.

Comment: Ok, but what is your question?

Comment: Put a *magic bowl* next to your andriod device. Any other prommissing approach will need to scan the file.

Comment: You could create an index of the contents of your PDFs and search that index.

Comment: @ThomasBöhm my question is "is it possible to search for a string or a text inside a pdf file without possibly opening that pdf?" Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to search text in a PDF file w/o reading its content. What you may find - it is strings and names(field names, document info, metadata etc.), and it will work only if the document is not encrypted.
All streams in a PDF document are compressed(mostly using FlateDecode filter).

Comment: How about opening the pdf in the background with the visibility off or something then searching for that string and closing afterwards and if that string is inside that pdf then the title of that pdf will be the result in that search.

Comment: Do you mean open it by Adobe in the background ? How are you going to open it ? I think you need some extraction/search tool for PDF documents.